# Attempting to create a custom hook using redux and dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm currently attempting to create a custom hook, as in my app I re-use the same function a lot of times at the moment in a few different places, and it's not sustainable.

The function is meant to call useDispatch() upon completion of an action, and it then updates state with a given payload.

However, when I try to move it into a custom hook, it throws an error saying the following:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component.

This is the hook in question - it's located in a useDispatchStatus.ts and is exported as a default:

```
const useDispatchStatus = (payloadMessage, payloadType) => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

    dispatch(displayStatus({
        payloadMessage: payloadMessage,
        payloadType: payloadType
     }))
 
     setTimeout(() => dispatch(hideStatus()), 5000)

}

export default useDispatchStatus
```

This 'hook' is then called inside of a function, located inside a component, like so:

```
const eventHandlerFunction = () => {

  try {
   // some example code in here
  } catch (error) {
   useDispatchStatus(error, "error")
  }
}
```

The hook itself is using a typical useDispatch(), but is a custom type since it's a TypeScript app, as defined in the RTK docs.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eventHandlerFunction` is not a React component, so you cannot call your hook from there. Hooks can only be called at the top level of a function component, or from another hook. To fix the error you need to move your hook out of the `eventHandlerFunction` function.

To fix this, try returning the dispatch function from the hook and calling that inside of the event handler:

```
const useDispatchStatus = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const dispatchStatusDisplay = (payloadMessage, payloadType) => {
    dispatch(
      displayStatus({
        payloadMessage: payloadMessage,
        payloadType: payloadType,
      })
    );
    setTimeout(() => dispatch(hideStatus()), 5000);
  };

  return dispatchStatusDisplay;
};

// Inside the component 
const dispatchStatusDisplay = useDispatchStatus()


const eventHandlerFunction = () => {

  try {
   // some example code in here
  } catch (error) {
   dispatchStatusDisplay(error, "error")
  }
}
```

The general idea is to export some function from the hook that can be called when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way for me to rewrite my code to make this more scalable? Feels like a really inefficient way to do this.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example. It's untested but should put you on the right track.

Comment: I get it - thanks for the response, appreciated!